# How can I set the width of one div to the margin of another div?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set the width of a div to the same value as the margin of another div, and I think jQuery is the solution, however I can't get it to work on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6y6esp8h/).

The current jQuery code I have is:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var w = $('#content').css("margin-left");
  $('#wrapper').css("width", $w);
})
```

Basically I want a sidebar that fills the width of the left side margin of the content area, and puts them side by side.

Also, any other suggestions on ways to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: You setting width for #wrapper to undefined $w variable. Use just **w** in 3rd line

Comment: Your jsFiddle has some errors. Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/6y6esp8h/5/

Comment: To start with, you need to add the jQuery library, or nothing will work. Then, check your browser console for errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () { // <--- Added brackets around document
    var w = $('#content').css("margin-left");
    $('#wrapper').css("width", w); // <--- Removed $ from $w since your variable is w not $w
}); // <--- Added ;
```

Also, be sure to import the JQuery library.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6y6esp8h/9/)**